# Using Booking.js with GatsbyJS requires Jquery Dependency Gatsby build fails but development works

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to use this booking widget from timekit.io https://developers.timekit.io/docs/booking-widget-v2#getting-started It works in development in Gatsby but the build fails with error `WebpackError: Cannot find module 'jQuery'` I have tried the reccomendations here to no avail https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/

It's a shame this widget relies on jquery. I am seriously considering just using the api manually and building the interaction, but for the client this was the best cost solution.

Thanks ahead of time.

Here is my code thus far

```
//gatsby-node.js
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions }) => {
  const { setWebpackConfig } = actions
  setWebpackConfig({
    externals: {
      jquery: "jQuery", // important: 'Q' capitalized
    },
  })
}
```

```
//gatsby-ssr.js
const React = require("react")

export const onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }, pluginOptions) => {
  setHeadComponents([
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossOrigin="anonymous"
    ></script>,
  ])
}
```

```
//html.js
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

export default function HTML(props) {
  return (
    <html {...props.htmlAttributes}>
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
        <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />
        {props.headComponents}
      </head>
      <body {...props.bodyAttributes}>
        {props.preBodyComponents}
        <div
          key={`body`}
          id="___gatsby"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }}
        />
        {props.postBodyComponents}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

HTML.propTypes = {
  htmlAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  headComponents: PropTypes.array,
  bodyAttributes: PropTypes.object,
  preBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
  body: PropTypes.string,
  postBodyComponents: PropTypes.array,
}
```

```
//index.js
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import $ from "jquery"
import TimekitBooking from "timekit-booking"

const IndexPage = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const widget = new TimekitBooking()
    console.log(widget)
    const config = {
      app_key: "fdsf",
      project_id: "fdsa",
    }
    widget.init(config)
  })


  return (
    <>
      <div id="bookingjs"></div>
    </>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```